# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "book_still_pkey" DETAIL: Key (number)=() is duplicated

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

That is my 2 migration where I try to change one field 'number'
But I have the error :

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "book_still_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (number)=() is duplicated.
```

models.py BEFORE migration

```
link_number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Link number', validators=[
                MinValueValidator(1),
                MaxValueValidator(MAX_TAG_NUMBER),])
        number = models.CharField('Number', max_length=8, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False),])
```

models.py AFTER migration

```
link_number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Link number', validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1),
        MaxValueValidator(MAX_TAG_NUMBER),])
number = models.CharField('Number', max_length=11, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False),])
```

my migrations 003:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('book', '0003_auto_20510907_1254'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='library',
            name='number',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, editable=False, max_length=8, unique=True,),
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='library',
            name='link_number',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[django.core.validators.MinValueValidator(1),
                                                          django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator(99999999)]),
        ),
```

Than I changed my field 'number' in models.py and create new migration 004:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('efish', '0004_auto_20210901_2050'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='library',
            name='id',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='library',
            name='number',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, editable=False, max_length=11, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='library',
            name='link_number',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default='', validators=[django.core.validators.MinValueValidator(1),
                                                                      django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator(
                                                                      99999999)],preserve_default=False,),
]
```

I think the problem in primary key!Anybode can help ???Please

Comment: post your model(s)

Comment: @Jonas Please!Updated my question!)Please check

Comment: Can you post the models before your changed the number field as well?